# java: is there a point to call super() if no args taken as parameter in constructors?

Tags: java

```
 abstract class Animal {
     private String name;
     public Animal() {
         this.name = "someName";
     }

     public String getName(){
         return this.name;
     }
 }

 class Dog extends Animal {
     private String breed;
     public Dog() {
         // super();   <----- not calling it
         this.breed = "someBreed";
     }
 }


 public class TryOO {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Dog dog = new Dog();
         System.out.println(dog.getName());
     }
 }
```

OUTPUT

```
someName
```

it looks like it has set the variable without calling super() from Dog?
It looks like no need to call super() if both abstract class and the class which extends it takes no parameter in their constructors.

Is this true?

Comment: According to the docs, the call to `super` is implicit on cases where `super` has no parameters.

Comment: We do not need to call explicitly super if it does not take any argument. Java will automatically call it.

Comment: ah thank you wanted to confirm